# How do I read PVZ Endless Mode Sequences?

Tags: terminology, plants-vs-zombies

A lot of PvZ endless strategies have a description in the form of a sequence to make it easier to understand. A sequence might be `C2: I-N | I-AA'` or something like that.

I've got the basic understanding on how to read these sequences. However, my personal translations are inconsistent and there are even more symbols that I don't understand. Like this one: `CH5u: PPSSDD | IPA-B-PD/PP | IPPP-PPDD | PPSSDD | IPA'a-B-PD/PP | IPPP-PPDD (6, 16, 14)`.

Is there some old forum post somewhere or something that lists conventions for these sequences? Like a list of all symbols and their meaning, and proper conventions?